# Saving selected options React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an Component with selected options like size and type.
I want to pass this selected options as props to another Component.
I save the active options using hook useState().
May be I need to create and save these options with id in another state, I don't know.
Please, can you help me, guys?

size and type are Arrays

There is my code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import AddBtn from '../AddBtn';

export default function Content({ id, imageUrl, name, types, sizes, price }) {
  const [typeActive, setTypeActive] = useState(0);
  const [sizeActive, setSizeActive] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="pizza-block">
      <img className="pizza-block__image" src={imageUrl} alt="Pizza" />
      <h4 className="pizza-block__title">{name}</h4>
      <div className="pizza-block__selector">
        <ul>
          {types &&
            types.map((type, index) => (
              <li
                key={index}
                onClick={() => setTypeActive(index)}
                className={typeActive === index ? 'active' : ''}>
                {type}
              </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
        <ul>
          {sizes &&
            sizes.map((size, index) => (
              <li
                key={index}
                onClick={() => setSizeActive(index)}
                className={sizeActive === index ? 'active' : ''}>
                {size}"
              </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="pizza-block__bottom">
        <div className="pizza-block__price">from &euro;{price}</div>
        <AddBtn id={id} type={} size={} /> //how to get type and size from State?
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Content.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  imageUrl: PropTypes.string,
  types: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  sizes: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  price: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: In general with you shouldn't pass down redux data to child components. You should connect the component that you want to have the data in to redux so you can access it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are in the same component, state is easy to be shared, whenever type or size changed will reflect on the whole component.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import AddBtn from '../AddBtn';

export default function Content({ id, imageUrl, name, types, sizes, price }) {
  const [typeActive, setTypeActive] = useState(0);
  const [sizeActive, setSizeActive] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="pizza-block">
      <img className="pizza-block__image" src={imageUrl} alt="Pizza" />
      <h4 className="pizza-block__title">{name}</h4>
      <div className="pizza-block__selector">
        <ul>
          {types &&
            types.map((type, index) => (
              <li
                key={index}
                onClick={() => setTypeActive(index)}
                className={typeActive === index ? 'active' : ''}>
                {type}
              </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
        <ul>
          {sizes &&
            sizes.map((size, index) => (
              <li
                key={index}
                onClick={() => setSizeActive(index)}
                className={sizeActive === index ? 'active' : ''}>
                {size}"
              </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="pizza-block__bottom">
        <div className="pizza-block__price">from &euro;{price}</div>
        <AddBtn id={id} type={typeActive} size={sizeActive} /> //how to get type and size from State?
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Content.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  imageUrl: PropTypes.string,
  types: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  sizes: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  price: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: Well, It's look easy, so I'll try to implement it.